# More elegant way of incrementing values in dictionary

Tags: powershell, hashtable

I am using this code to increment a table value:

```
$ip = "8.8.8.8"
$httpFailure = @{}
$httpFailure.set_item($ip,($httpFailure.get_item($ip)+1))
```

So, if a website fails to respond, it will go from 0 to 1, even if there is no entry in the hash table to begin with. Any subsequent calls to this code will increase it to 2,3,4,5 etc.

Is there a more elegant way to do this? It makes my code extremely long and ugly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello there handsome gentleman, yes indeed there is a way.

This would be the short way of what you have posted above:

```
$ip = "8.8.8.8"
$httpFailure = @{}
$httpFailure["$ip"] += 1
$httpFailure[$ip]++
```